# How to comapare button tag value

Tags: android

I am developing a quiz application in which I have 3 ans buttons.
I am comparing every button tag value of button for ex `Ans_1.getTag() == "1"` but its always gives me false.

here is my code

I am setting the tag value here

```
            Ans_1.setTag(is_right_choice[0].toString());
            Ans_2.setTag(is_right_choice[1].toString());
            Ans_3.setTag(is_right_choice[2].toString());
```

`is_right_choice[0].toString()` this value is coming from json response but when I compare it

```
     if(Ans_1.getTag() == "1")
            {
                Ans_2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                Ans_1.setEnabled(false);
                Ans_2.setEnabled(false);
                Ans_3.setEnabled(false);
                points.setText("+1 Punkt");
                is_button_click = true;
                isCancelled = true;

            }
            else
            {
                if(Ans_2.getTag() == "1")
                {
                    Ans_1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    Ans_2.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    Ans_1.setEnabled(false);
                    Ans_2.setEnabled(false);
                    Ans_3.setEnabled(false);
                    points.setText("0 Punkt");
                    is_button_click = true;

                    isCancelled = true;

                }
                if(Ans_3.getTag() == "1")
                {
                    Ans_3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    Ans_2.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    Ans_1.setEnabled(false);
                    Ans_2.setEnabled(false);
                    Ans_3.setEnabled(false);
                    points.setText("0 Punkt");
                    is_button_click = true;

                    isCancelled = true;

                }

            }
```

it doesnt compare in any if block. can any one tell me what I am doing wrong here.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use .equals method for compare two Objects

```
if(obj1.equals(obj2)) {
..
}
```

in your case (seen that tag contains a string), you should use:

```
if(Ans_1.getTag().toString().equals("1")) {
..
}
```

or more simply..

```
if(Ans_1.getTag().equals("1")) {
..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to override the **equals** function (along with others) to use this with custom classes.

The equals method compares the objects.

The **==** binary operator compares mem addresses.

So Change this

```
if(Ans_1.getTag() == "1")
```

to

```
if(Ans_1.getTag().toString().equals("1"))
```

and same for `Ans_2` and `Ans_3` buttons